# Is it possible to run a single Android CTS test case from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, junit, cts

I am currently dealing with some CTS issues for our own device. It comes to my mind that if we can run a single CTS test case just from Eclipse, that would be very helpful for debugging the CTS issues.
For example, I have create an Android test project, with the manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.content.pm.cts"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="android.content.pm" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the source code:

```
 package android.content.pm.cts;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

public class ResolveInfo_DisplayNameComparatorTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    private static final String MAIN_ACTION_NAME = "android.intent.action.MAIN";
    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "android.content.pm.cts.activity.PMTEST_SERVICE";


    public void testDisplayNameComparator() {
        PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
        DisplayNameComparator dnc = new DisplayNameComparator(pm);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MAIN_ACTION_NAME);
        ResolveInfo activityInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);

        intent = new Intent(SERVICE_NAME);
        ResolveInfo serviceInfo = pm.resolveService(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);

        assertTrue(dnc.compare(activityInfo, serviceInfo) < 0);
        assertTrue(dnc.compare(activityInfo, activityInfo) == 0);
        assertTrue(dnc.compare(serviceInfo, activityInfo) > 0);
    }
}
```

When I right click on the project and select "run as android junit test" it just report: Test run failed: Unable to find instrumentation target package: android.content.pm

I know that I might be totally wrong from the beginning. So could anyone please point out a correct way out for me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because the android OS cannot find an application installed with the package "android.content.pm" and eclipse does not know about the project in order to install it for you, install the application you want to test (and check its package is in fact android.content.pm which it probably isn't because that is a system package and you will not be able to instrument against that because your debug signature is not the same)

Comment: Yes, after these days I think your explanation is quite reasonable. Thanks.